# Code to print in the Qgis console the values ​of the attribute table that are selected in the shapefile

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I found a code that prints all data that a shapefile has in the attribute table in the qgis console. But i wanted to have a code that just printed the data that i select in the shapefile. Can someone help me?

I'll leave here the code that prints all the data.

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

features = lyr.getFeatures()

featList = []

selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()

for feat in features:

featList.append(feat.attributes())

featList.sort()

for f in featList:

print f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it... just loop over `selected_features` and indent the code properly:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

selected_features = lyr.selectedFeatures()
featList = []


for feat in selected_features:
  featList.append(feat.attributes())

featList.sort()

for f in featList:
  print f
```